# Call the event handler only once even when on double click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Firstly, I do not want to use `removeEventListener` once my event is fired. Because, I need it to fire each time user clicks on the element.

And I have looked at similar questions. This is not a duplicate, let me explain how:

I have a Favorites button, which on click, displays the list of items I have bookmarked earlier. It works. But when I double click, it ends up calling the function twice for some reason.

This is the code against comments of what it does:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.getElementById('favButton').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    $('#favorites').show(); // shows the bookmarks div element
    $('#front').hide(); // hides the homepage and irrelevant details to current search
    addFavorites(); // populates the bookmarks
  });
});
```

and in `addFavorites()`:

```
function addFavorites()
{
    $('#favorites').empty();
    // code to populate bookmarks
}
```

I need it to work each time I click the Favorites without any reload. And I need it to stop populating Favorites twice if I double-click (on single click, it populates once only).

The issue in a picture:
[image: addFavorites_called_twice]

*Something weird observed:* With the same code, the issue does not appear on Chrome 64 bit version on Linux, but shows up on Chrome 32 bit version (same version number though) on Windows.

Appreciate any direction to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. Both `addEventListener` calls are missing ending parenthesis.

Comment: Debugging 101: add `console.log()` commands to pin down if the event listener is called and how often. Also: [mcve]

Comment: @SimpleJ Yup, corrected them, thanks. I had copy pasted part of the code and missed this.

Comment: @ChrisG Okay, I will do that, thanks

Comment: @nj2237 You should probably also post the full code, since the error is most likely in a part we can't see yet.

Comment: @ChrisG I thought so too, but the code is quite large. And also, this behavior is equivalent to putting two `addFavorites()` so I thought the inside of the function wasn't an issue. I could be wrong of course, and the full code for this function starts here - https://github.com/OpenGenus/quark/blob/2a1c3d48f1e78fedd18449e52400bf2a50831d78/code/js/popup.js#L338

Comment: You could also disable the button at the start of your function, enable it again at the end. If you do not want the user clicking quickly or double clicking, then place a setTimeout in of around a second to ensure the disable/enable is visible and that it can't be clicked on until re-enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following.

```
document.getElementById('favButton').addEventListener('click', function(event){
    //if it has already been clicked, return and don't repeat
    if (this.getAttribute('data-clicked') == 'true') return;
    //marked it as already clicked
    this.setAttribute('data-clicked', true);

    $('#favorites').show(); // shows the bookmarks div element
    $('#front').hide(); // hides the homepage and irrelevant details to current search

    //if you need this to work multiple times you can make the method
    //return a promise (I assume you are doing some ajax) that will
    //resolve when the request is done
    var promise = addFavorites(); // populates the bookmarks

    //we can undo the attribute when it finishes so the logic will repeat
    var thiz = this;
    promise.always(function(){
        thiz.setAttribute('data-clicked', false);
    });
});
```

Comment: This seems to answer the title of the question, not the slightly different issue in the question details though. The button has to work multiple times, just not within a very short time. It's also unclear how the code causes twice the content to show up, given that is start out emptying the div.

Comment: Depending upon how fast it is, both of them could get past the empty part, both run the ajax, and then both append to the content area.  @ChrisG

Comment: @Taplar thanks for your answer, let me check this out

Comment: @Taplar Right, the populating must be asynchronous then.

Comment: @Taplar it does display once on double click, but once I click on other tabs and come back, the click event doesn't fire and the favorites tab isn't shown - on console I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'always' of undefined`

Comment: `addFavorites()` should return the promise from your $.ajax or whatever ajax call you are doing.

Comment: @Taplar Oh okay! So what should I add after the return statement in my `addFavorites` function? I'm sorry, I'm trying to read what Promises are

Comment: Looking at the github you linked above, i'm thinking the method should have `return chrome.storage.sync.get(....` in that method.  I'm assuming the `get` should return a promise, but it may not be a jQuery promise, so if it is not we may have to change the answer slightly from an `always` to a Promise/A+ compliant method.

Comment: If someone else is familiar with `chrome.storage.sync.get` and if it is async or not, it'd be awesome for a clue in.  If it is not async then this solution changes a bit.

Comment: @Taplar I'm trying to find that out too.. meanwhile have my upvote as a thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166556/discussion-between-taplar-and-nj2237).